# Using authorization code to complete Owin authentication

Tags: android, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin

I have created an Android app that uses OAuth2 authorization code flow to get an authorization code from the Facebook authorization server.  This works correctly, and I am able to retrieve the authorization code in my app after the user logs in and authorises it.

I would now like to pass that code to a .NET WebApi server to complete the flow on the server to retrieve the access token and, subsequently, the user's details from Facebook.  I have scoured the web for examples of how to use this code, combined with the classes from Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, to complete the signin process, but I cannot find anything.  Is it possible to authenticate a user using an authorization code I have already retrieved rather than the standard Microsoft.Owin.Security process of redirecting the browser to the authorization url?  Or will I have to write something custom?

Comment: Usually you send the `access_token` to your WebApi where it checks the signature against the public key of the provider (facebook in your example). If the signature matches, then you have a valid `access_token` and can identify the user.

Comment: So do I retrieve the access_token in the Android app?  Do I then just add this token as a Bearer token on any Http request to the server?

Comment: You need to check how Facebook handles it specifically but usually yes. You include the `Authorization: Bearer xyz` header in every request. (But only if you need to be authenticated for that specific request)

Comment: Thanks for that.  One final question, how does WebApi know which provider to test my token against?  If, for example, I have Facebook access_tokens and Google access_tokens, how does the server know which provider to authenticate against?

Comment: The `access_token` contains a field called `iss` for issuer, containing (most of the time) the URL of the Provider that created the `access_token`. So for example you'd have field `"iss": "https://api.facebook.com/"`